# Integrating Spring Batch with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, integration, spring-batch

Can you guys guide me to some nice tutorial containing `Context-Configuration`(**applicationContext.xml**) details and some example code for running a simple batch job using [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) from within my [Spring MVC Web-App](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) or help me in the same way here only.

*THanks*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please search the web more before posting a question. These links might help you

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2012/02/spring-batch-tutorial-part-1.html

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2012/02/spring-batch-tutorial-part-2.html

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2012/02/spring-batch-tutorial-part-3.html

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2012/02/spring-batch-tutorial-part-4.html

Comment: The website is outdated and the code examples are lost. Unfortunately it's no longer worth reading.